# Regex: change date format

Tags: regex, date, notepad++, utc, replace

I have a list of dates formatted as **mm/dd/yyyy**. In order to fit them into the javascript UTC method, they have to be in format **yyyy,m-1,dd**. How can I use regex find replace (in Notepad++) to accomplish this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most definitely **not** do this with the limited regular expression support of notepad ++. You can't subtract values with regex(*only*).

Either use perl or some other language to do what you want.